# How to display World Bank API info for a country by country name instead of iso2Code?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have created a Angular app with a service that retrieves country information from the World Bank API so that I can display the Name, Capital, Region, Income Level, Longitude, and Latitude of any country that is searched. I can use the text input field to successfully show the 6 properties of a country by searching for its 2 digit iso2Code, but not by the countries name. It doesn't seem that the WB API lets you query the search by the countries name.

My code:

worldbank.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WorldbankService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCountryProperties(countryName: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${countryName}?format=json`;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

country-info.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WorldbankService } from '../worldbank.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-country-info',
  templateUrl: './country-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./country-info.component.css']
})
export class CountryInfoComponent {
  countryName = "";
  countryProperties: any = null;

  constructor(private worldbankService: WorldbankService) {}

  getCountryProperties() {
    this.worldbankService.getCountryProperties(this.countryName).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.countryProperties = data[1][0];
      }
    );
  }
}
```

country-info.component.html

```
<div class="right-column">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="countryName" placeholder="Enter a country name" />
    <button (click)="getCountryProperties()">Enter</button>

    <ul class="properties-list" *ngIf="countryProperties">
        <li>Name: {{ countryProperties.name }}</li>
        <li>Capital: {{ countryProperties.capitalCity }}</li>
        <li>Region: {{ countryProperties.region.value }}</li>
        <li>Income Level: {{ countryProperties.incomeLevel.value }}</li>
        <li>Latitude: {{ countryProperties.latitude }}</li>
        <li>Longitude: {{ countryProperties.longitude }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried storing the data from the API call in a array and then comparing the user input to see if it matched the value of any property in the array. I wasn't sure how to select and store the whole object in its own array so I could display the needed properties from it. Also wasn't sure if this was the correct approach.

Answer (score -1):

Use this api:

```
https://api.worldbank.org/V2/country/{two letter country code}
```